# How to run various workers on OpenShift?

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I have a Python/Flask project (API) that contains a few workers that must be run continuously.  They connect to Redis using an outside provider (https://redislabs.com/).  I didn't find how can I configure Openshift to run my workers.  When using Heroku, it was as simple as:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi --log-file -
postsearch: python manage.py worker --queue post-search
statuses: python manage.py worker --queue statuses
message: python manage.py worker --queue message
invoice: python manage.py worker --queue invoice
```

But for Openshift, despite googling many things, I was not able to find anything to help me.  Ideally, I would avoid deploying my application to each gears.  How can I run multiple workers with OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from `Getting Started with Openshift by Katie J. Miller and Steven Pousty`

> Cartridge
>
> To get a gear to do anything, you need to add a cartridge. Cartridges are the plugins that house the framework or components that can be used to create and run an application. One or more cartridges run on each gear, and the same cartridge can run on many gears for clustering or scaling. There are two kind of cartridges:
>
> Standalone
>
> These are the languages or application server that are set up to serve your web content, such as JBoss, Tomcat, Python, or Node.js. Having one of these cartridges is sufficient to run an application.
>
> Embedded
>   An embedded cartridge provides functionality to enhance your application, such as database or Cron, but cannot be used on its own to create and application.

TL;DR:  you must use cartridges to run a worker process. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html) and [here](https://developers.openshift.com/get-involved/extend-openshift.html), and the community-mantained examples [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin-community-cartridges) and a series of blog post begins [here](https://blog.openshift.com/new-openshift-cartridge-format-part-1/)

A cartridges is a bunch of file and a manifest to let OS know how to run the cartridge and how to resolve a deps.

But let's build something. Create a Django/Python app, the result is:

[image: the demo django app]

Now install your (custom) cartridge from the link on the bottom or from the command line tool, you can use the link to the cartridge repository.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift's integration with external services is done by configuring the relevant environment variables as explained at: https://developers.openshift.com/external-services/index.html#setting-environment-variables

Heroku's apps rely on a `REDISCLOUD_URL` env var that is automatically provisioned - you'll need to set up something similar in your OpenShift deployment with the applicable information about your database from the service's dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was about how can I run the workers on my gear ? (running a wsgi application and 4 long running processes) ?

Comment: Ok - missed that... I'll assume that your Google-fu is as least as good as mine so no use trying to do "flask gear openshift environment variable" :)

Comment: Ahah yes indeed ;) I may expressing myself incorrectly, but my question is about "how can I run two different process in Openshift ?". I know how to use the env variables in Flask, the issue here is to run the main web server PLUS some `while(True):` redis queue. It's those `while (True):` queue that I don't know how to run.